# How can I get a number from user in telegram bot?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ8ga.jpg)

I want to make something like 'a button, when the user press this button A question will appear to him: Do you want to share your contact with the bot?,' I want like this using curl in bash script:

and I try like this, but it is doesn't working

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

token=""
old=$(curl -s "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/getUpdates" | awk 'END{print}' | sed -n -e 's/^.*"date"://p' | cut -d ',' -f1)

while true; do
new=$(curl -s "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/getUpdates" | awk 'END{print}')
if [[ "$new" =~ \"chat\"\:\{\"id\"\:([\-0-9]+)\, ]]; then
    CHATID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi

if [[ "$new" =~ \"date\"\:([0-9]+)\, ]]; then
    DATE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi

TEXT=$(echo "$new" | sed -n -e 's/^.*"text":"//p' | cut -d '"' -f1)

if ! [ "$DATE" = "$old" ]; then
echo "text: $TEXT, from: $USERNAME, id: $CHATID"


if [ "$TEXT" = "/start" ]; then
    curl "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/KeyboardButton?chat_id=$CHATID&text=flase&request_contact=true"
fi

old="$DATE"
fi
done
```

And error code is:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}%
```

I try like this but It's now working how can I done this in right way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ8ga.jpg

Comment: I have no idea what the responses you're processing look like, but I think they're in JSON, so use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse them, not regex, sed, awk, and cut.

Comment: Please include the error you receive or what the current outcome is when you run your code.